# ORA-20002: YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO CHANGE THE PASSWORD FOR CRITICAL SCHEMAS

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm trying to change the password for Oracle DB user but I'm getting below error:

```
ORA-28003: password verification for the specified password
ORA-20002: YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO CHANGE THE PASSWORD FOR CRITICAL SCHEMAS
```

I've tried to change the password using sys user and got same error.
DB version: 12.2.0.1.0
Client: SQLPlus

Please help

Comment: ORA-2xxxx errors are custom application errors. You probably have a trigger that prevents this. It's not buil-in Oracle error

Comment: I believe it's coming from a password verification function rather than a trigger, but same principal - it's your own code (or your DBA's) that is causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is being raised by a password verification function, assigned to the user via a profile.

You can see the profile name and the function being applied by querying:

```
select du.profile, dp.limit
from dba_users du
join dba_profiles dp on dp.profile = du.profile
where du.username = '<YOUR_USER>'
and dp.resource_name = 'PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION';
```

You can then see what the function is actually doing by looking at its source, using the name identified in the previous query:

```
select text
from dba_source
where owner = 'SYS'
and name = '<FUNCTION_NAME>'
order by line;
```

From there you can see when and why it's happening, by looking for a line like:

```
raise_application_error(-20002, 'YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO CHANGE THE PASSWORD FOR CRITICAL SCHEMAS');
```

and seeing what logic leads to it being raised.

You'll need to decide whether that rule is (still) appropriate for that user - clearly it's there for a reason so don't remove it or change the user's profile without really understanding it, and discussing with the DBA and/or application owner etc. - basically anyone with an interest in that user account.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. It turned out that the verification function doesn't allow any password change and I had to change the profile to DEFAULT and change it back after changing the password. Thanks a lot!